# Getting a value from a dynamic object dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0

Yes, title sounds a bit confusing, so I'll explain what I mean: suppose you have a C# 4.0 'dynamic' object, and the name of a property.  How would you retrieve that property from the dynamic object?

In other words, how would you implement:

```
public static object GetDynamicValue(dynamic o, string name) { ... }
```

Another way to put it is that I'm trying to treat a dynamic object as an IDictionary.

Note that reflection is likely not an option here, since the dynamic object could be a custom implementation which is not reflection based (e.g. by extending DynamicObject and doing its own thing).

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about your use case? If you want to have a dynamic object that is similar to IDictionary, why not use ExpandoObject, for example? Jon's suggestion probably works, but I have a feeling that this is a too complicated solution for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would have to build a call site, create a binder etc.

The easiest way to see what happens is to compile this:

```
public static object GetDynamicValue(dynamic o, string name)
{
    return o.Foo;
}
```

Then decompile it with Reflector and work out what it's doing. It'll be pretty complicated, mind you - and you'll need to change it from being a single, static, cached call site to creating a new one on each invocation.

Here's an example which does work... but whether it's *entirely* correct or not is a different matter :) (I got this going by doing exactly what I suggested above.)

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Test
{
    public static object GetDynamicValue(dynamic o, string name)
    {
        CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>> site 
            = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create
            (Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, 
             typeof(Test), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] 
             { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));
        return site.Target(site, o);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetDynamicValue("hello", "Length"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks Jon!  That brings a lot of concepts that I haven't dealt with, so I'll need to study it carefully.

It feels strange that typeof(Test) is used in there, since it should be of no relevance.  But I tried setting it to null and the code still works, so apparently it wasn't doing much.

Comment: It's relevant in terms of what members are accessible - you'll be able to get at private members of Test using this code, but not private members of other types.

Answer (score 3):

The Open source framework ImpromptuInterface (available in nuget) does this, and does the extra work involved because caching the call site is important for performance.

See [InvokeGet](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.InvokeGet%28object_target,_String_Or_InvokeMembe)

```
public static object GetDynamicValue(dynamic o, string name) {
        return Impromptu.InvokeGet(o,name);
}
```

Comment: @David-Ebbo While Clay allows you to access it's own properties via string name, `InvokeGet` allows you to access ANY IDynamicMetaObjectProvider properties via string name (or any regular object faster that reflection)...unless I am missing something.