# Best way to access a member of a dynamic object when I know the member name?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0

Given a dynamic object and a string member name:

```
string AMemberNameIKnowExists = "SomeMember"; //determined at runtime
dynamic myDynamicObject = //...
```

I want to access the "SomeMember" member on my dynamic object. Do I have to use the standard reflection tools or does the fact that I have a dynamic object give me a better way to resolve a member by name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a value from a dynamic object dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926776/getting-a-value-from-a-dynamic-object-dynamically)

Comment: agreed jbtule (and well-found).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use `DynamicObject`'s [`TryGetMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx) method:

```
myDynamicObject.TryGetMember(new GetMemberBinder("SomeMember", false), out result)
```

As far as I understood `dynamic`, that's what a dynamic call like `myDynamicObject.SomeMember` gets translated to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get property value form the object

```
myDynamicObject.GetType()
               .GetProperty("SomeMember")
               .GetValue(myDynamicObject, null);
```